# Gitlab Job keep output blank line when using nuget

Tags: docker, gitlab, nuget

I have a gitlab CI job, which use nuget to list nuget package 
But the job keep output endless blank lines 
I test the script on my WSL, it works.  
Hava no idea what the problem is.

```
stages:
  - deploy

Push: 
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install nuget -y  && apt-get clean
    - nuget list Newtonsoft.Json.Bson
```

Comment: If you view the full raw log for the job, do you see anything at all?

Comment: the full raw log will keep listing blank lines till the browser OOM